# Removing a node from a LinkedList (C#)

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list, hashtable

I created a `LinkedList` class with a function `delete` to remove a certain node from the list if found, however it's not working:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    public Node head;
    <...>
    public void delete(string n)
    {
        Node x = search(n); //returns the node to delete or null if not found
        if (x != null)
            x = x.next;
    }
    <...>
}
```

I figured all I needed to do is find the node and set it to the next one (so the node is "removed" out of the linked list), however it's not. If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

EDIT: Forgot to mention I have a single linked list.

EDIT2: My new code:

```
    public void delete(string n)
    {
        Node x = head;
        while (x != null && x.name != n)
        {
            if (x.next.name == n)
                x.next = x.next.next;
            x = x.next;
        }
        if (x != null)
            x = null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing you doing anything to delete the item.  What makes you think that what you've done would delete the item?

Comment: You need the node before the one you want to delete and do something like `beforeDelete.Next = beforeDelete.Next.Next;`  with special treatment when the node you want to delete is the head.

Comment: @Servy I figured since it's no longer linked to, as the link to the node is replaced with the next node (like substituting the node by the next one in the linked list so it's no longer in it).

Comment: @user2999349 Setting the local variable to the next node isn't going to delete the node, no.  It's just setting a local variable.  The previous node is still linking to the node that the local variable used to refer to.

Comment: @user2999349 Currenly all you do is set the local variable `x` to the `next` node.  That node is still reference by the previous node.

Comment: @Servy That's what I was afraid of, but I thought it may be pointing to the actual node (obviously not though), however I have no idea how to access the actual node?

Comment: @juharr That's what I initially thought but I figured this would do the same thing because beforeDelte.Next = the node to be deleted, but didn't think it would make a difference accessing it directly, replacing it by the next node instead of adapting the next of the previous node.

Comment: @juharr Yes but then the previous node would point to x.next I supposed, since first it pointed to x which is now replaced by x.next (from my logics, but probably I'm missing something)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to loop through the list until the next node is the one you want to delete.  Then set the current to the next nodes next node.

```
public void Delete(string value)
{
    if (head == null) return;

    if (head.Value == value)
    {
        head = head.Next;
        return;
    }

    var n = head;
    while (n.Next != null)
    {
        if (n.Next.Value == value)
        {
            n.Next = n.Next.Next;
            return;
        }

        n = n.Next;
    }
}
```

This of course assumes you only want to delete the first match.

Comment: @user2999349 Note that I originally left out the `n = n.Next;` that's important if your list has more than one node and the first and second nodes are not the ones you want to delete.